# Avoid changes propagation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

First of all sorry for my bad English :D
Recently I'm studying more deeply Design Patterns because of an exam of Software Engineering and I have to design a software system as a project for this exam.

There is a problem that I cannot handle with: how to decouple entity classes (which represents the data of my application domain) from... everything else!

I mean, being more concrete, that if I have a class Patient (with its own private attributes and public getter and setter methods), this is an entity class, I think that so far I got it right :D

So let's say that I choose to design my program using the MVC pattern architecture, the class Patient will be in the Model, is that correct?

Now, every view that deals with that class, will have a reference to it: lets say I have three views: the first one to view all patients, another one to modify a patient, and the last one to register a new patient (actually there will be other classes in which I should present some reports, but I think this is irrelevant now).

Each one of these classes will know the structure of Patient in order to show its data, e.g. they will call its getter methods and show the data in some way.

I think that there is no way to avoid this, since a view is semantically tied to the data (=model) it has to show: I mean that it has to know whether a data is a string, a date or an integer and it has to know also its semantics (what it represents in the real world); so I think that doesn't make much sense just removing references to the class Patient.

Now the heart of the problem is:
How to prevent that a change in the class Patient propagates to all classes (not only views) that uses it?

I mean: let's say that the attribute String Cellular changes in String[] Cellular because of a change in the requirements. I will have to modify:
1) DB / DB interfaces
2) Patient class
3) (worst of all) every class that uses Patient!!

How to avoid this?
I think that in a good project a change in a single class should not propagate in a chain of changes to all modules that uses that class, but I'm a beginner and I can't think of a way to prevent this.

I can't even think of a good way to use a stable interface for entity classes, since a change in the requirements will reflect in a change to the interfaces (and I don't think that interfaces are meant to be changed!).

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment that comes to mind is that you say you have to change a bunch of classes that use that Cellular attribute like it's a bad thing.

This is actually one of the features of strongly typed languages. It ensures that types remain consistent across the entire system where that attribute is used.

For example, if the Cellular field changes from String to String[], of course your DB model should also be adjusted to reflect the change from a 1-1 relationship to a 1-many relationship, and therefore your data access objects (or ORM layer configuration) need to be adjusted to reflect the change. It's a good thing that the compiler does not let you get away with it.

Another comment is that only classes that uses the Cellular field will need to be be adjusted. But here again, it's a good thing. So if you had a user interface that collected the cellular number of the patient, now the compiler is letting you know you should really allow the user to collect multiple numbers.

When designing software, it's critically important to spend a lot of time getting the model as right as possible. And knowing that the requirements will change to some degree, it's also critically important to not be scared of refactoring. Modern IDEs like Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ can assist and do most of the busy refactoring work on your behalf.

Comment: The fact is that I've always been told (and I've been used to think so) that when a single change causes many changes in several modules, the design has some serious flaws.

So I'm just a little bit worried that I'm not doing things "well" :)

Comment: Generally speaking, it's true. It would mean you have too many dependencies on a single component. For core model objects however, it's usually a bit different because often your system is all about dealing with the model. This being said, try your best to keep the pieces that related together or close by.

Answer (score 0):

Not all changes can be isolated to the model or view or persistence layer.  But in your case you can make Patient model have a list of contact fields which are generic.  The view gets a list of them and populates some editable text boxes for the user.  The DatabaseMapper persists these fields generically as well.

So adding Cellular can be done purely in the model unless the GUI needs to change more drastically.  You don't start building it generically unless you know you need to but you can refactor to it.

Comment: I meant to find a solution for something more generic than just the example I did.

The fact is that I need (if exists) a general solution, not a specific one :)

Comment: Use MVP or MVVM which provide better layer isolation and changes will rarely affect code in more than two layers.

Answer (score 0):

For your entity classes, I think you should leave the interface abstraction to the end, after you've defined all your business entities and can extrapolate a common behavior pattern among them. Only then can you infer a common interface among them. But your entity classes are ultimately concrete; there's no sense in trying to abstract them further.

Ultimately changes to these concrete classes would require changes to the controllers/views also interacting with them. Don't fret over this. Once you've defined all your views for each entity, then you can start working out the abstractions, if there are any.

If you have already defined your concrete entities, then you can start abstracting away for views. For a financial example, suppose I have a Trade class. Obviously I can have specific types of trades, such as a BondTrade, EquityTrade, etc. So I can also have a TradeView, which can have concrete views, i.e. BondTradeView, EquityTradeView, etc. You can have a higher level of abstraction, but ultimately, you'll need concrete classes that would define a specific view.

[Look at the Facade Design pattern as an example.](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) The facade can be used to create views based on your concrete implementations. It's a way of unifying all your concrete entities. It would contain the logic to know what view to create, and how, based on your entity. This would be a way to simplify the propagated changes done on your entities.

Comment: Actually, I already have defined all my business entities and I've got a quite good idea about how they will interact.

So, you think that there's no way to prevent that a change in a concrete entity class propagates to many modules?
Isn't this contrary to good design?

Comment: I went ahead and enlarged the answer, since it wouldn't fit in this comment box...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the following statement:

> Each one of these classes will know the structure of Patient in order
>   to show its data, e.g. they will call its getter methods and show the
>   data in some way.

Is only a half truth.  Your view should not know what a `Patient` is.  It probably has something called `PatientView` as the model it operates off of.  So the piece that sits in between the model and the view needs to perform a mutation.  Which essentially looks like this:

```
public PatientView convertPatient(Patient patient)  
{  
    return new PatientView(patient.foo(),patient.bar(),etc);  
}
```

The contract of the function guarantees a `PatientView` object is returned to the invoker, subsequently this class is part of the interface defined by the class that encapsulates it.  This also has the advantage of the view not knowing what a `Patient` is.

Any change in the underlying model, i.e. the thing that drives your entire application, will of course causes some type of ripple effect.  The use of converters helps to minimize the touch points as no parts of your application should really know what a `Patient` is and there should be a connector between each area: view,controller,etc that converts a Patient into what is being expected for that part of the application.

Comment: This seems to me pretty much like using Transfer Objects.
But, actually, I think that just removing references to `Patient` from the views does not mean that they do not know its structure; in facts in order to show some `Patient`'s data, the view has to know its precise semantics (e.g. it has to know if an attribute is a number and what it represents, the same for dates and everything else).

Comment: And probably neither Transfer Objects nor the addition of intermediate levels would solve the issue: since `PatientView` would hold `Patient` data, any change in `Patient` would reflect into `PatientView` and subsequently in the classes that uses `PatientView`.

Either this, or I just didn't got the real meaning of `PatientView` :D :D

Comment: @tmh if you read the entire post you may have seen the following: `Any change in the underlying model, i.e. the thing that drives your entire application, will of course causes some type of ripple effect.`  What I am saying is your `VIEW` should not know what a `PATIENT` is.  Actually the classes that use `PatientView` don't know nor do they care about a `Patient`.  It generally helps to ensure that the model is correct before doing an implementation of it.

Comment: I read the entire post, but what I mean is that the view may not know what a `Patient` class is, but it _must_ know what a Patient is in terms of its structure and the semantic of its attributes; how could a view show a Patient's id, his name or his birth date, if it ignore that the `id` is a number, the `name` is a string etc etc?
So if a field changes its semantic, a view that has to handle that field can not remain unaffected by this change, even using additional levels... so any change to `Patient`'s attribute will reflect in `PatientView` first, and then in all the views.

Comment: It's different what happens for Patient's operation: interfaces usually can solve the problem, because if something changes, the interface remain the same. But if I can abstract well on operations, I find more difficult to perform a good abstraction on data.

Comment: @tmh if you find yourself abstracting well on functions than abstracting on the data has already been accomplished.  This is because you should not be exposing the internals of your class hence the getter/setter paradigm.  It should go without saying any change to your MODEL will result in a change to the way the application functions.